# html2canvas renders blank image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I am trying out html2canvas for the first time for converting my html element to an image. However, it renders a blank image instead. Here is a reproducer:

```html
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

```js
const div = document.createElement(('div'));
div.innerHTML = '<h1>asd</h1>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
 
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(div, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u07oL18v/)

Somehow on removing the target div, it renders correctly. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I can see a number of workarounds here and I also discovered a few myself. What I am trying to understand is why this is happening so I avoid having such issues in my app?

Comment: Also working correctly if the target div is moved after the script (tested on Edge). What browser are you using?

Comment: And works correctly if replace the call tohtml2canvas(div)  with html2canvas(document.getElementById('target') - even when the target div is in its original position before the script.

Comment: Yes. I tried a number of different solutions. I am trying to handle a bigger case in my app and trying to understand why exactly is this happening. How to use html2canvas to avoid such things?

Comment: The problem is that the JS-created div is not properly in the DOM when it gets used by HTML2canvas - I think we have to force a reflow or something to make sure it is there. I have put up half an answer and hope to have a full one shortly.

Comment: I suspect my last comment is not quite right. In desperation I took the code from the question, plus the html2canvas library and made a complete document. It is on my own space and it seems to work see [link]http://ahweb.org.uk/testhtml2canvas.html or my updated answer. Can you tell me if it works for you? If so I think there is some interference with other libraries, either those imposed by jsfiddle or something else you are using.

Comment: I am now convinced the basic code works. I have put now it into an SO snippet and into a jsfiddle (the whole lot as a complete HTML document) and it works.

Comment: Found it! If you use your jsfiddle but change the id of the Lorem ipsem div to something else, for example id="ahtarget" the code works. So maybe it's quite simply that some code (HTML2canvas maybe) is also trying to use that id. It would also explain why putting the Lorem Ipsem div after the script works - because if another div exists with that id it will above it and will (temporarily) be the one that is found by for example a getElementById.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 23 Oct 2020: The problem was that there is a div with id="target" before the script. If that is renamed then the jsfiddle works successfully. It seems that something (possibly in jsfiddle) uses the id "target" temporarily and was picking up the wrong one. (moving the div with id target to below the script also worked, probably because the temporary target would have been found first in the DOM).

Several attempts at debugging this were made and the info is kept here because the answer was accepted without the paragraph above and for completeness.

If the div (which has the <h1.... code) is put before the script as HTML rather than being created by the script it is put onto the canvas successfully.

Likewise, the div with id target can be put onto the canvas successfully.

So this will work:

```
<div id="div"><h1>asd</h1></div> 

window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('div), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
```

(this is not pretending to be a complete answer, but it is too long for a comment)

UPDATE: I moved away from jsfiddle and instead put a complete example up on my own space so I know there is nothing else going on. See it on [http://ahweb.org.uk/testhtml2canvas.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484937/html2canvas-renders-blank-image) It seems to work.

Here is the complete code. Seems familiar? It is the code from the question without extras (e.g. the stuff jsfiddle has to put in or other libraries that are invoked)

And let's try it in a snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484937/html2canvas-renders-blank-image -->
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<script>
let div = document.createElement(('div'));
div.innerHTML = '<h1>asd</h1>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
 
function takeScreenShot() {
    html2canvas(div, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if the complete document is put into the HTML part of a jsfiddle, with nothing extra in the JS part, it works. So jsfiddle is probably exonerated and it is something in some other library that is interfering ... to be continued...

Comment: Oh now I get it. So probably, even in my app it is due to some other node modules which may be creating an issue. Thanks for the insights. Will take a better look at what is going on over there.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the width and height - let html2canvas decide for itself the dimensions of the canvas.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyhw02a7/1/

```js
const div = document.createElement(('div'));
div.innerHTML = '<h1>asd</h1>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
 
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(div, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            console.log(canvas);
        }
});

}
```

```css
#target{
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" integrity="sha512-s/XK4vYVXTGeUSv4bRPOuxSDmDlTedEpMEcAQk0t/FMd9V6ft8iXdwSBxV0eD60c6w/tjotSlKu9J2AAW1ckTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

Comment: But why does it work? I am trying to understand the reason behind these small fixes to address a bigger use case in my app.

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with setting the canvas dimensions, but it is to do with putting your code into an SO snippet instead of jsfiddle. The snippet works. I have found the same sort of thing (see my answer) and that works without having to change any dimensions. The finger is pointing at jsfiddle.